# Getting javascript error while posting data by creating HttpURLConnection

Tags: java

I was trying to connect to the weblogic server using the HttpURLConnection.

Below is my request method:-

```
  private void sendPost(String url, String postParams) throws Exception {

      URL obj = new URL(url);  
      conn = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();  


        conn.setUseCaches(false);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Host", "<IP-ADDRESS>:7001");
        conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept",
                "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");


        conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Referer", "http://<IP-ADDRESS>:7001/console/login/LoginForm.jsp");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(postParams.length()));




        if (cookies != null) {

            conn.addRequestProperty("Cookie", cookies.split(";", 1)[0]);

    }

        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setDoInput(true);


        // Send post request
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
        wr.writeBytes(postParams);
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();

        int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
        System.out.println("Post parameters : " + postParams);
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

    BufferedReader in = 
             new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();


  }
```

in the above code the
postParams = "j_username=weblogic&j_password=weblogic1&j_character_encoding=UTF-8";
url = "http://IP-ADDRESS:7001/console/j_security_check";

I am unable to login into the WebLogic Administration Console.

Getting the error :-

JavaScript is required. Enable JavaScript to use WebLogic Administration Console.

Please help and let me know how to enable java script ?

Comment: Also would like to add that the Login button in weblogic doesnt have any name just the value = "Login" as described below.

<input class="formButton" type="submit" onclick="form.submit();this.disabled=true;document.body.style.cursor = 'wait'; this.className='formButton-disabled';" value="Login">

 So do i have to add it in my postParams?

Comment: You're getting that from whatever page the server redirects you to after the login.

Comment: You cannot just enable javascript. You would have to write you own JS processing egine, eg. using `ScriptManager`